# How to find index of more than 2 duplicated number array and convert the item at index into ascending order?

Tags: javascript, html

let arr = ['**1**','5',***'2'***,'**1**','4','**1**','9','**1**',***'2'***];

output = ['**1**','5',***'2'***,'**2**','4','**3**','9','**4**',***'3'***];

**1** is a **duplicate** in arr. Thus, **all the 1** in arr is converted into ascending order **1,2,3,4**

**2** is also a **duplicate** in arr. Thus, **all the 2** in arr is converted into ascending order **2,3**

Please provide a demo. Thank you very much for your kind perusal.

Comment: You're post is difficult to understand. What is your expected result? If it's your output, then that really makes this confusing.

Comment: My output is stated above. Input is  arr. Output is output

Comment: Your ouput doesn't make sense. You show output of `[1,5,2,2,4,3,9,4,3]`, so you moved the 2's together, but you removed all the extra 1's. How does this show an expected output?

Comment: Hi, you mean you dont understand the ques?

Comment: What's exactly your problem with this task? It looks like a homework task and I'm not going to solve it for you. But if you are stuck at a specific problem with this task, what's this problem?

Comment: Errm i am building an app. Not homework. I am a mechanical engineering student

Comment: @RyanWilson As I understood it: While (some number has 2+ occurences): replace 1st occurence with number, 2nd occurence with number++, 3rd occurence with number+2, etc

Comment: yes A_A you are right.

Comment: Say you replace the second 1 with a 2, do you then replace that same 2 with some other number if its now a duplicate 2?

Comment: @MaximusSu Then that would have been helpful in your post.

Comment: @MaximusSu Ok, but at what part of this are you stuck? Checking if there is a duplicate? Replacing it? Looping?

Comment: Oh. Nvm. Actually, I can solve it on my own. Just that i want quicker answer from stack overflow. I believe you all are working at tech companies, Am i wasting yall time? I am 18 years old.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let arr = ["1", "5", "2", "1", "4", "1", "9", "1", "2"];
let flag = {};
let ret = arr.map((x) => {
  x = +x;
  if (!flag[x]) {
    flag[x] = x;
    return x;
  } else {
    flag[x] += 1;
    return flag[x];
  }
}).map(x => x + "");
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: This is the answer i am looking for. What a concise answer. Thank you. Please upvote this guy.

Comment: it looks like i take the same approach in a shorter style. ++

Answer (score 3):

You could take a single loop approach with a replacement value for the next mapping. This approach takes only numbers, but if wanted you could convert all values to numbers

For any duplicate number, it takes the incremented value from the object.

```
1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 9, 1, 2
1        2     3     4
      2                 3
```

```js
const
    array = [1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 9, 1, 2],
    values = {},
    result = array.map(v => v in values ? ++values[v] : (values[v] = v));

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can get the duplicated index information for the `input` array.
- It will be got as this format.

```
{
  1: [0, 3, 5, 7],
  9: [2], ...
}

// Values are the duplicated index position.
```

- Based on that info, you can replace the data on that index which has more than 2 duplicates using `Array.splice` function as follows.

```js
const input = [ '1', '5', '2', '1', '4', '1', '9', '1', '2' ];

const duplicates = input.reduce((acc, curV, curI) => {
  acc[curV] ? acc[curV].push(curI) : acc[curV] = [curI];
  return acc;
}, {});

let output = [ ...input ];
Object.entries(duplicates).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
  if (value.length > 1) {
    for (let index = 1; index < value.length; index ++) {
      output.splice(value[index], 1, (parseInt(key) + index).toString());
    }
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply